# Setting a tkinter variables using a generic set_value() method

Tags: python, variables, types, tkinter

I'd like to have a generic method that will change the value of a tkinter variable.  I want to be able to do this from a menu option that brings up a new dialog box which is from a generic method that can be used for different variables.  the code I have so far is below:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sequencer as seq


class View(ttk.Frame):
"""Main Gui class"""

def __init__(self, master = None):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, borderwidth=5, width=450, height=500)
    self.master = master
    self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    ###############################
    ### User editable variables ###

    self.precision = IntVar(value=4, name='precision')
    self.sensitivity = IntVar(value = 50, name='sensitivity')

    ### User editable variables ###
    ###############################

    self.create_menus()


def create_menus(self):
    """Produces the menu layout for the main window"""

    self.master.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)

    self.menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.master['menu'] = self.menubar

    # Menu Variables
    menu_file = Menu(self.menubar)
    menu_edit = Menu(self.menubar)

    # Add the menus to the menubar and assign their variables
    self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file, label="File")
    self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_edit, label = "Edit")

    ### ADD COMMANDS TO THE MENUES ###
    ### File ###
    menu_file.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.master.destroy)

    ### Edit ###
    menu_edit.add_command(label="Backbone", command=lambda : self.edit_backbone())
    menu_edit.add_command(label="Precision", command=lambda : self.precision.set(self.set_value_int("Precision")))
    menu_edit.add_command(label="Sensitivity", command=lambda : self.sensitivity.set(self.set_value_int("Sensitivity")))
    menu_edit.add_command(label="print precision", command=lambda : print(self.precision.get()))
    menu_edit.add_command(label="print sensitivity", command=lambda : print(self.sensitivity.get()))

def set_value_int(self, name):
    """Standards dialog that return a user define value of a specific type"""

    t = Toplevel(self)
    t.title("Set " + name)

    label = ttk.Label(t, text="Set "+name)
    label.grid(row=0)
    entry = ttk.Entry(t)
    entry.grid(row=1)
    cancel = ttk.Button(t, text="Cancel", command=lambda : t.destroy())
    cancel.grid(column=0, row=2)
    okey = ttk.Button(t, text="Okey", command=lambda : okey(entry.get()))
    okey.grid(column=1, row=2)

    def okey(value):
        """return value according to type"""
        try:
            t.destroy()
            return int(value)
        except:
            self.error_box("value must be and integer")


def error_box(self, error_message="Unknown error"):
    """(Frame, String) -> None
    Opens an window with an Okey button and a custom error message"""

    t=Toplevel(self)
    t.title("Error")

    label = ttk.Label(t, text=error_message)
    label.grid(row=0)
    okey = ttk.Button(t, text="Okey", command=lambda : t.destroy())
    okey.grid(row=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Sequencer")
    view = View(root)
    root.mainloop()
    print("End")
```

The Edit-> print xxxxxx commands are purely for testing purposes to check if the values have changed.  If these are executed before trying to change the values of precision or sensitivity then they work as expected.

If you try to change either of the tkinter variables in the way I have tried to do they become None types and I can't see why.  I can only assume that you are not allowed to change them in the way that I have but I can't think of another way to do it without having a separated method for each variable which I'd like to avoid.

Baicly I'd like the user to be able to customise the variables precision and sensitivity and use the same method in the code to change the values.

Extra but not necessarily  vital:- If there is a way to define which type the variable should be in the methods arguments as well that would be even better as I will have other variables for the user to change later and they will be of different types.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I have tried to be as clear as I can but let me know if anything is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.set_value_int` always returns None, so it's always going to set your variable to none.

Instead of trying to write a complex lambda that is hard to debug, put all of your logic inside the function. Have the function set the value. All you need to do is tell it what variable to set:

```
menu_edit.add_command(label="Precision", 
    command=lambda name="Precision", var=self.precision: self.set_value_int(name, var))
...
def set_value_int(self, name, var):
    ...
    def okey():
        s = entry.get()
        try:
            var.set(int(s))

        ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's been driving me mad.  A great help :-).  I would plus 1 but I'm not able too